# Scrapy next page, no sense results

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, cloudflare

Trust you are doing well!

I´m scraping some web pages and when I try to go to the next page I´m not able to, because the next page results, it doesn´t matter with what I´d look for at the first one.

An example:
Fist page look for: https://www.mister-auto.es/buscar/?q=corteco
Second page: https://www.mister-auto.es/buscar/?page=2

The problem that I´ve is that the results at the second doesn´t has no sense with what I´d look for.

I´m using crawlspider with linkextractor to go to the next.
Could you give me a hand?
Thank you very much for your support.

Answer (score 1):

The website you're scraping is **dynamic** and when you're changing pages it does not reflect in the URL.

What you want is a tool like [Puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) or [Selenium](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium) to render the page dynamically, click buttons and extract the content you want. While it is a great tool for certain jobs, Scrapy has its limitations.

Comment: Hi! Thank you very muh! From your point of view, what would you recommend me? Puppeteer or Selenium?

Comment: Both are very good. If you're good with Node.Js go with Puppeteer, and if you want more tutorials and browser compatibility Selenium has the upper hand (I think). It's really up to you honestly